# How to check if data shows in html table else if the data didn't show in the table it will failed using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a new problem in my automation testing and I need to check if the data in my tables exist.
For Example.. I have a table below. I need to check if the cat and dog exist in the table.. else it will failed. so I create a run keyword if to verify if the data exist but first I need to get all the data because sometimes he table is dynamic. This is my sample code. my problem is.. what if the data(Dog) didn't exist in the table?

${Count}  get element count  ${Table_Row}
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE   1  ${Count}

```
    ${Animals}  get text  xpath=//div[@id='table1']/table/tbody/tr/td[41]/div/table/tbody/tr[${i}]/td 
  
    Run Keyword If    "${Animals}" == "Dog"  Log to console  Dog Exist   ELSE  fail  Dog didn't exist
     
    END
```

[image: Sample table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to get all the elements of first column into a array, something like:

```
${animals}   Get WebElements   xpath=//"xpath for all elements in first column"
```

then with that you can run a for cycle to check each element and fail the test if you don't find whatever you need to find:

```
FOR   ${element}   in   @{animals}
   ${animal}   Get Text   ${element}
   Log To Console   ${animal}
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check first expected data exists or not

```
${data}=   Page Should Contain Element    element xpath
```

if not exists you can fail the test.

Please let me know if I am not understood your question correctly..